# What is that lighter color section on the right of Xcode Source Editor for?

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

You can see that there is a light-dark section in the coding file.

Any theme I choose can't fix this interesting section since my Xcode version is 6.

Now, my Xcode version is 7.2.1 and does anyone know my problem?

Thanks a lot!

PS: Now I un-check the page guide, but it looks like that:
[image]

Comment: try restarting your XCODE . if it don't work try restarting your mac .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "**Page Guide**", to help people keep their code within certain width so it'd be easier to read with different editor/screen.

You can disable/change it from the Xcode preferences:

[image: preferences]

Comment: Hey, now I un-check the page guide but also have a little section. - - You can see that in my new editing pic.

Comment: @Lanaya_HSIEH Mine do not. Try restart your Xcode and see if that helped. But you really don't need to worry about that as it does nothing besides showing a line there.

Comment: @Lanaya_HSIEH what about switch between themes?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a bit great than before although different themes don't fix the problem too. But you answer is helpful.